# Formatting NSString, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

What would be the best way to transform NSStrings like these (mixed case)

```
@"Hello lorem ipsum";
@"i am a test";
```

to these (camel case without spaces)

```
@"helloLoremIpsum";
@"iAmATest";
```

Comment: First capitalize your string, then remove the whitespaces. Check the `NSString` docs for the methods you need for this.

Comment: It's not. Removing the whitespaces is only a part of it. Why downvote?

Comment: split to words, capitalize words exluding the first one, join them into a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**Using For Loop**

```
- (NSString *)camelCased:(NSString *)aString  {
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString new];
    NSArray *words = [aString componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < words.count; i++) {
        if (i==0) {
            [result appendString:([words[i] lowercaseString])];
        }
        else {
            [result appendString:([words[i] capitalizedString])];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Using Block**

```
- (NSString *)camelCasedUsingBlock:(NSString *)aString  {
    NSMutableArray *words = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [[aString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id anObject, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (idx == 0) {
            [words addObject:[anObject lowercaseString]];
        }
        else{
            [words addObject:[anObject capitalizedString]];
        }
    }];
    return [words componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}

NSLog(@"%@",[self camelCased:@"Hello lorem ipsum"]);//helloLoremIpsum
NSLog(@"%@",[self camelCased:@"i am a test"]);//iAmATest
```

Comment: Nitpick - Use `NSUInteger` for the `for` loop variable's type. That is the type used by the `count` property and the various array index methods. There is also no reason for the `(NSString *)` casts.

Comment: 1. You should iterate using fast enumeration. 2. Maybe the code is clearer, if you put the fragments in an array and then join it with `-componentsJoinedByString:` with an empty string.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I thought about using fast enumeration. But how can I get index?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR You can actually only check whether `test` is empty.

Comment: @Sulthan I dont want to check array count. I need to check index of array elements.

Comment: 1. You're already checking the array count. Look at your loop: `i < words.count`. 2. You can check for the string length, you can leave the string reference uninittialized and check for `nil`, you can use a boolean. I think, that all of this is more expressive.

Answer (score 0):

It's overkill but [TransformerKit](https://github.com/mattt/TransformerKit) has a bunch of `NSValueTransformers` that can be used, one is for camel casing. The relevant file is [TTTStringTransformers.m](https://github.com/mattt/TransformerKit/blob/master/TransformerKit/TTTStringTransformers.m) if you want to build your own solution for lightness.

Comment: @ThatlazyiOSGuy웃: Read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) the section about: 'And all those other answers with links in them'. Remove the markup, and the answer still has meaning. If `TransformerKit` is gone or removes that feature, than there is no helping, but till then even without the link, it is an answer, though (I dont have the expertise in that) maybe disputable whether it is a *good* one. It could e.g. be improved by adding details on how to use it from `TransformerKit`

Comment: i apologize for my mistake but there could be an example instead of only link reference

Comment: I feel like linking to the actual source code of a project solving the problem on github is a reasonable answer to the problem. There's a question around whether reproducing code from a public repo is acceptable dependant on the license they use.

Comment: FYI the reason I linked to source code is "teach a man to fish" rather than "give a man a fish".